# how to use ngif properly in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ng-if

I found angular project on github and I was trying to continue work on it so that I can learn but I'm stuck on how to use ngIf properly.

so I have my three chart type inside chart.model.ts file and I'm not sure who to access that data in my design.component.ts file so that I can make the Text box to show only when the user select Text on drop down list.

right now, the three chart type options are showing on drop drop list when ever I run the project but not doing anything and also I got an error on my ngIf saying that

"Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ChartType'."

I would be really appreciate if can somebody teach me or help me.

chart.model.ts

```
export class ChartUtil {
    public static getChartTypeDisplay(type: ChartType): string {
        switch (type) {
            case ChartType.chart:
                return "Charts";
            case ChartType.text:
                return "Text";
            case ChartType.grid:
                return "Grid";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

export enum ChartType {
    chart = 1,
    text,
    grid
}
}
```

design.component.ts

```
import { ChartType } from 'src/app/chart.model';


 chartTypes: ChartType;


  setupTypes() {
    keys = Object.keys(ChartDataType);
    for (let i = 0; i < (keys.length / 2); i++) {
      this.dataTypes.push({ value: parseInt(keys[i]), display: ChartUtil.getChartDataTypeDisplay(parseInt(keys[i])) })
    }
}
```

design.component.html

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="chart.chartTypes == chartTypes.text">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput />
            </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I can't uploaded the full project on stackblitz but I uploaded all the code from those file over https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmf3vn

Comment: Can you mention what ChartType model contains?

Comment: @ZainZafar hi I'm not really sure what you mean but in chart.model.ts file I saw this,  export class ChartConfig { type: ChartType; }     export class Chart{chartType: ChartType = CharType.chart } and 
export enum ChartType {
    chart = 1,
    text,
    grid
}

Comment: You need to initialize the chartTypes too `chartTypes: ChartType = ChartType.text`. Since all of the code isn't posted that's what makes the most sense

Comment: In your component you have declared a field of type ChartType, which only limits the values that can be assigned as those from the enum.  Change it to chartTypes: ChartType = ChartType; and your ngIf should work.

Comment: @testpossessed  I did but not sure why I still getting an error. I would be really appreciated if can you guy can take a look at the whole code from those file https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmf3vn . thanks

Comment: All the errors in that stackblitz are because your names are not as expected in the imports.  For example you are importing app.module but the module is design.module and you have no app.component

Answer (score 0):

ng-If works such that if the condition is true the code written inside the ng-if **will be rendered/displayed** in HTML. If the condition is false then the code **will not be rendered/displayed**. So based on your condition set the value to true or false.

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="displayChartInfo">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput />
            </mat-form-field>
```

In your ts,

```
 displayChartInfo:boolean = false;
    public static getChartTypeDisplay(type: ChartType): string {
            switch (type) {
                case ChartType.chart:
                    this.displayChartInfo =true;;
                      break;
                case ChartType.text:
                     this.displayChartInfo =true;;
                      break;
                case ChartType.grid:
                     this.displayChartInfo =true;;
                      break;
                default:
                    this.displayChartInfo =false;;
                  break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: some reason it saying " Property 'displayChartInfo' does not exist on type 'typeof ChartUtil'." even those I added "displayChartInfo: boolean = false;" in my export class CharUtil.

Comment: can u debug and check whether getChartTypeDisplay method got called ? Can u provide a stackblitz example ?

Comment: hi..I don't think I can upload the full project since it contains a lot of file and modules but I have uploaded the all code inside those files. If you don't mind please take a look over here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmf3vn thanks

Comment: hi if there is no return "Chart" on switch statement, how the three option will be display when I replace with this.displayChartInfo=true.